# How can I create a mapping function for 1000 elements in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've manually created a mapping function(map) to map some elements of an RDD.

```
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(
  LabeledPoint(5.0, Vectors.dense(1,2)), 
  LabeledPoint(12.0, Vectors.dense(1,3)),
  LabeledPoint(20.0, Vectors.dense(-1,4))))

  val map = Map(5 -> 0.0, 12.0 -> 1.0, 20.0 -> 2.0)

  val trainingData = rdd.map{
    case LabeledPoint(category, features) => LabeledPoint(map(category), features)
}
```

How can I create a mappping function for 1000 elements. These 1000 elements are in a RDD called distinct.
I have tried this

```
var i=0
val map=distinct.map
      { x=>Map(x -> i)
        i=i+1
      }
```

But this cannot be used as mapping function for

```
val trainingData = rdd.map{
          case LabeledPoint(category, 
  features) => LabeledPoint(map(category), features)
        }
```

Comment: can you explain more of your map function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zipWithIndex` and then `collectAsMap`:

```
val distinct = sc.parallelize(Seq(5, 12, 20))

distinct.zipWithIndex.collectAsMap
// res2: scala.collection.Map[Int,Long] = Map(20 -> 2, 5 -> 0, 12 -> 1)
```

Comment: Is there any way to re-map to the original? @Psidom